# Three.Js object file is loadded but material files are not loading

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, .obj, wavefront

I created 1 small object file in the blender tool and then exported it to wavefront (.obj) format.

My code:

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setPath( 'objs/' );
mtlLoader.load( 'final_blue_cup.mtl', function( materials ) {
    materials.preload();
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
    objLoader.setPath( 'objs/' );
    objLoader.load( 'final_blue_cup.obj', function ( object ) {
        scene.add( object );
    }, onProgress, onError );
});
```

This is my output from my blender tool:
[image: this is my output from my blender tool]

This is what is get after load in three.js:
[image: this is what is get after load in three.js]

With this link you can find my object, material and blender file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XW_teF6N3qqmqavsQrPpLZntJoMvqL0K

Can anyone help me in fixing it?

Comment: none of the attributes in your mtl file are bluish. they are all grayish.

Comment: i also attached .blend file and its rendered output file in .png in point (1)